# Add a rel nofollow to shortcode in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, nofollow

I use a button shortcode for my WordPress (see below).

As you can see, I can choose a color, put the link, specify something for the target attribute.

I would like to add rel nofollow to this wordpress button link shortcode but I don't know how to do it.

```
add_shortcode('button', 'shortcode_button');
function shortcode_button($atts, $content = null) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'color' => 'black',
            'link' => '#',
            'target' => '',
        ), $atts);

        return '[raw]<span class="button ' . $atts['color'] . '"><a href="' . $atts['link'] . '" target="' . $atts['target'] . '">' .do_shortcode($content). '</a></span>[/raw]';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You want that dynamic ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by dynamic ? (sorry I'm a noob)

Basically, all the next button links I will create with the button shortcode need to be in nofollow.

Comment: Okay I have posted the answer try with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add  `rel="nofollow"` in your a link.

```
add_shortcode('button', 'shortcode_button');
function shortcode_button($atts, $content = null) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'color' => 'black',
            'link' => '#',
            'target' => '',
        ), $atts);

        return '[raw]<span class="button ' . $atts['color'] . '"><a rel="nofollow" href="' . $atts['link'] . '" target="' . $atts['target'] . '">' .do_shortcode($content). '</a></span>[/raw]';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! It works.

I would vote but don't have enough reputation sorry.

Comment: Don't be. Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

use the below code... you have to use the `do_shortcode()` inside your this function. the reason is you are using another short code inside this.

```
add_shortcode('button', 'shortcode_button');
function shortcode_button($atts, $content = null) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'color' => 'black',
            'link' => '#',
            'target' => '',
        ), $atts);

        return do_shortcode('[raw]<span class="button ' . $atts['color'] . '"><a href="' . $atts['link'] . '" target="' . $atts['target'] . '" rel="nofollow" >' .do_shortcode($content). '</a></span>[/raw]');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I've not tried the code you gave me but I've searched a little bit about the do_shortcode(). Look like it can be bad for some people, I don't know in my case...